# Terraform private provider registry with alternative to gpg

Tags: terraform, gnupg, openpgp, terraform-cli

I'm implementing a private provider registry in Go, according to the specification
the [find a provider package](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/internals/provider-registry-protocol#find-a-provider-package)  response should contain the `gpg_public_key`.

The go [opengpg](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp) is no longer maintained and not recommended, and [few alternatives](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/44226) are suggested. Especially for provider registry implementation, where we need to sign the shasum document, this https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/ed25519 seem to be the best bet.

However, my question is that if the ed25519 generate signature compatible with terraform cli? or Terraform CLI only work with gpg generated signature.